# Terraform - Access map object using for_each

Tags: foreach, terraform

I am using for_each inside a module and using each.key to dynamically get the value from a map

```
dynamo_without_index = ["employee"]

tf.vars.json File content

{
  "accounts": {
    "dev": {
      "dynamodb": {
        "employee": {
          "name": "employee",
          "read_capacity": 2,
          "write_capacity": 2
        }
     }
    }
  }
}


module "dynamo_create" {

  source = "../modules/dynamodb"
  for_each = toset(var.dynamo_without_index)

  read_capacity = var.accounts[terraform.workspace].dynamodb.${each.key}.read_capacity
}
```

I am unable to find the right syntax to substitute ${each.key} value to get the value 2 from the map "accounts"

Comment: What exactly is `var.dynamo_without_index`? What errors do you get?

Comment: dynamo_without_index = ["employee"] .. Its a list of string.. This matches the field in the "accounts" map. I am trying to access account.dev.dynamodb.empoyee.read_capacity.. I am trying to substitue ${each.key} with the item in the list dynamo_without_index

Comment: OK. So what's the issue? What errors do you get?

Comment: It says "$" is not valid. If i give var.accounts[terraform.workspace].dynamodb.employee.read_capacity it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square brackets instead:

```
read_capacity = var.accounts[terraform.workspace].dynamodb[each.key].read_capacity
```